# StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase Equals vs GetHashCode disagree for equal objects

Tags: c#, .net

StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase Equals returns true for "" vs "\0", but GetHashCode return different values for the two strings. Is this a bug?

```
var sc = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
string s1 = "";
string s2 = "\0";
Console.WriteLine( sc.Equals(s1, s2)  );
Console.WriteLine( sc.GetHashCode(s1) );
Console.WriteLine( sc.GetHashCode(s2) );
```

returns

```
True
0
-1644535362
```

I thought that GetHashCode should return the same value for 'equal' strings, so is this a bug?

Comment: which flavor of .net?

Comment: the lengths of the strings are different. the hash code is only one indicator to determining whether a string could be equal or not. the string comparer has culture specific logic in it and im guessing a `\0` is just ignored.

Comment: This happens with .NET Framework 4.7.1 and 4.6.2. I haven't tried others

Comment: Appears to be a bug in .NET. As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243461/stringcomparer-invariantcultureignorecase-equals-vs-gethashcode-disagree-for-equ#comment95312998_54243913) in the comments, `IEqualityComparer<T>` is [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.2#notes-to-implementers) to return equal hashes for strings for which its own `Equals()` returns `true`. `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` implements `IEqualityComparer<string>`.

Comment: The culprit appears to be the zero hash for the zero-length string, not the addition of `\0` per se. The comparer appears to return equal hashes when both strings have non-zero lengths (e.g. `"a"` and `"a\0"`).

Comment: The problem is reported to MS: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/430327/stringcomparers-may-return-different-hashcodes-for.html

Comment: I noticed that when calling string.GetHashCode() on both strings it does return the same value, so this must be related to the StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase. But I still agree with you that if Equals is True then GetHashCode _should_ return the same value.

Comment: MS closed the problem as Won't fix.

Comment: For .NET Framework, they stated that they would not fix it due to backwards-compatibility issue. For .NET Core, it have been labelled a bug and hopefully there would be a fix... or at least an explanation for the reason for such behaviour. (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34662) Been a while ago, but just in case you're wondering.

Answer (score -3):

Those 2 strings are not bitwise equals. They are 2 different lengths. Hence, the hash code algorithm is being reasonable here.

The string comparison algorithm must be ignoring `\0` when doing its comparisons. I [looked into the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Globalization/CompareInfo.cs,c4d01e30d323bbaa,references): It is doing some sort of add/subtract comparison algorithm to find out if things are different.

`GetHashCode` only implies that values *may be* equal, not necessarily they are. The inverse is not always true, you can override the `==` operator or `.Equals` for any type and have it produce `true` when the hash codes don't agree.

Here's [`GetHashCode`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/String.Comparison.cs,0a17bbac4851d0d4,references). It looks like it's using the raw bytes for calculation.

You may have stumbled on an obscure bug in the .NET libraries, but I'm guessing that this is an edge case.

Then again - you are using a string comparer. Not the `string.Equals` method or `string.GetHashCode`. Notice that `Console.WriteLine("\0".Equals(""));` produces `false`.

<strike>If you want a string comparer that would have it agree, I believe `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` would do the trick since it looks at each character separately, instead of collating on the values.</strike> *It looks like both just funnel to the same character comparison method.*

Comment: It would make sense for the generic `string.GetHashCode()`, but it's `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode()`, surely it must return same hash for strings that it itself is going to deem equal?

Comment: @GSerg not necessarily.

Comment: I don't get it. In mass comparisons `Equals()` is called only for pairs with equal hashes, so how can a comparer be allowed to return unequal hashes for equal strings?

Comment: its the `\0` char. it in effect has no effect on the string

Comment: *The inverse is not always true, you can override the `==` operator or `.Equals` for any type and have it produce `true` when the hash codes don't agree.* [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.2#notes-to-implementers) seems disagree with that: *Implementations are required to ensure that if the `Equals(T, T)` method returns `true` for two objects `x` and `y`, then the value returned by the `GetHashCode(T)` method for `x` must equal the value returned for `y`.*

Comment: @PetSerAl "required to ensure" gives wiggle room. its a rule that can be broken

Comment: @PetSerAl i tested with the string class directly and get the expected result.

Comment: It's not the `\0`, it's the `""` for which there is apparently a hardcoded zero hash. The comparer does return equal hashes for two non-zero length strings one of which ends with `\0`. I would also object to the *Then again - you are using a string comparer*: it is correct that a string comparer is used, and it does not matter what `string.GetHashCode()` would have returned.

Comment: @GSerg its not hard coded its calculated `""` has length of 0. The `"\0"` has length of 1.

Comment: Method signatures are not the only part of contract of interface. Expected behavior is part of contract too, although C# does not provide a way to express this part in the code. If you broke that rule, then you have broken implementation.